# The regular expression finds only the first parameter in Qt5

Tags: regex, qt, qt5

What's wrong with my regular expression? According to the plan there should be two elements, but only the first one is defined.
Qt5.12 MinGW32 Windows 7x86.

```
QRegExp rx("\\d+");
QString buf_last;
buf_last.append("read0_1");
rx.indexIn(buf_last);
auto try_step     = rx.cap(0).toInt();
auto current_step = rx.cap(1).toInt();
qDebug() << try_step << current_step << buf_last << "rx___" << rx.cap(0)
         << rx.cap(1) << rx.capturedTexts();
```

[bug-report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-79787)

Comment: That's the same in all regex languages I know (if capturing supported at all): _Parentheses allow us to group elements together so that we can quantify and capture them._ I took this from the doc. where you will find the correct example as well: [QRegExp - Capturing Text](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#capturing-text). (Of course, parentheses outside of quotes don't count.) Btw. the Qt bugtracker is intended for Qt bugs but not for application programmer bugs... ;-)

Comment: And, please, have a look at [QRegExp::cap()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#cap): _The first element, cap(0), is the entire matching string. Each subsequent element corresponds to the next capturing open left parentheses._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no bug here, it's all according to the docs and how REs work in general.

If you're trying to find each digit in a string using `QRegExp` then you have to loop. One way to do it is:

```
int main(int , char **)
{
  QRegExp rx("\\d+");
  QString buf_last("read0_1");
  int idx = 0;
  do {
    idx = rx.indexIn(buf_last, idx);
    if (idx < 0)
      break;
    qDebug() << rx.cap(0);
    idx += rx.cap(0).length();
  } while (idx < buf_last.length());

  return 0;
}
```

```
"0"
"1"
```

This is only one way, especially the actual code style of the loop. Using a `QRegularExpression` may be a lot more efficient, depending on your needs. But finding an arbitrary number of digits like that is going to involve a loop somewhere.